# Active Reports changing the textbox value at the runtime

Tags: c#, activereports

In the Active reports, Depending on the datafield value I have to change the value of the textbox at runtime I'm trying to do it as follows:

```
private void PageHeader_Format(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtManifestType.Text == "Mixed Single")
    {
        txtManifestType.Text = "Flats";
    }           
}
```

Help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where is txtManifestType located, in PageHeader or in some other section?

is it bound to some other data field?

what behavior are you seeing.

the code you have should work if the textbox is in the PageHeader.    Have you debugged the code to see if the condition is met to change the value?